# Who is Reuben's tribal head upon entering the promised land?

Tags: numbers, genealogy

In Numbers 1:5-16, we see the appointment of the princes or chieftains of the tribes of Israel. In verse 5 we clearly see the tribal head for Reuben:

> And these are the names of the men that shall stand with you: of the tribe of Reuben; Elizur the son of Shedeur.

But in Numbers 34:16-29, the listing of those to apportion the land of Canaan does not have anyone for the tribe of Reuben:

> **19**And the names of the men are these: Of the tribe of Judah, Caleb the son of Jephunneh. **20**And of the tribe of the children of Simeon, Shemuel the son of Ammihud. **21**Of the tribe of Benjamin, Elidad the son of Chislon. **22**And the prince of the tribe of the children of Dan, Bukki the son of Jogli. **23**The prince of the children of Joseph, for the tribe of the children of Manasseh, Hanniel the son of Ephod. **24**And the prince of the tribe of the children of Ephraim, Kemuel the son of Shiphtan. **25**And the prince of the tribe of the children of Zebulun, Elizaphan the son of Parnach. **26**And the prince of the tribe of the children of Issachar, Paltiel the son of Azzan. **27**And the prince of the tribe of the children of Asher, Ahihud the son of Shelomi. **28**And the prince of the tribe of the children of Naphtali, Pedahel the son of Ammihud. **29**These are they whom the LORD commanded to divide the inheritance unto the children of Israel in the land of Canaan.

Was this a scribal error or what was the reason for a tribal head of Reuben not to be listed? Who was to head the tribe of Reuben?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see the context:

> Numbers 34:13 Moses commanded the Israelites: “Assign this land by lot as an inheritance. The Lord has ordered that it be given to the nine-and-a-half tribes, 14because the families of the tribe of **Reuben**, the tribe of **Gad** and the half-tribe of Manasseh have received their inheritance.

In Numbers 34:16-29, two tribes are missing: Reuben and Gad. Moses wrote only about the ten tribes inheriting the land west of Jordon.

Comment: Ah, yes. I had missed that about Gad and about them not having a land inheritance west of the Jordan.

Comment: Glad to be of service :)